# Disable listview item click

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

How to disable click event on listboxitem which is bound?

I have managed to set visibility to false on items but it is not enough because even though item is invisible it still fires event when clicked on that area. This my item:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="stolTemplate1">
        <Grid Visibility="{Binding konobar, Converter={StaticResource IsItMyTable}}"  Height="155"  Width="155">
            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding suma, Converter={StaticResource tablePictureConverter}}"/>
            </Grid.Background>
            <Grid Height="27" Width="Auto" Visibility="{Binding suma, Converter={StaticResource IsItMyTable2}}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="45,0,45,128">
                <Grid.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect/>
                </Grid.Effect>
                <Grid.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource tipkeNarPlaG1Color}" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF1E4D57" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Grid.Background>
                <Label Content="{Binding suma}"  Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16">
                    <Label.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect/>
                    </Label.Effect>
                </Label>
            </Grid>
            <Label x:Name="label" Content="{Binding broj_stola}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" FontSize="26.667" Background="{x:Null}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

This part:

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding konobar, Converter={StaticResource IsItMyTable}}"
```

Calls this part:

```
 Private Function IValueConverter_Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
   If value = Globals.konobar Or value = 0 Then Return Visibility.visible
    Return Visibility.Collapsed
End Function
```

Instead of visibility i want it to be IsEnabled = False/True.

Do I achieve this through ItemTemplate or maybe through ItemContainer?

Comment: Do you want to suppress selection? In other words: Do you want the listview items to be NON-selectable? If this is not what you are trying to achieve, what problem exactly are you trying to address and solve when saying "_disable click event on listview items_?"

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are few options how to do that:

- quick and dirty : create an extra converter for **IsEnabled** property

  `<Grid Visibility="{Binding konobar, Converter={StaticResource IsItMyTable}, IsEnabled={StaticResource YOUR_ISENABLED_CONVERTER}}"`
- create a boolean in your viewmodel, and bind it to your Visibility and IsEnabled/IsHitTestVisible property
- create a Dependency Property ("propdp" snippet) and bind it to your properties
- create an Attached Property/Behavior for your specific needs

IMO, its better doing every "logic-bound-thing" in your viewmodel.